# Refactor two almost identical methods that change different attributes

Tags: python, refactoring

So I just started working in a new codebase and I'm trying to help refactor some stuff. There's things like huge methods that should be splitted into chunks and so on. There's this method A that does the exact same thing as method B, with a small difference.

Let's say method A is:

```
def func_a(data):
    # Do some stuff...
    obj = get_obj_from(data)
    value = 0

    # Somewhere inside a loop
    for item in items:
        value += item.value_a

    obj.attribute_a = value

    # Do some other stuff...
```

And method B is:

```
def func_b(data):
    # Do same stuff as func_a()...
    obj = get_obj_from(data)
    value = 0
    count = 0

    # Somewhere inside a loop that does the same as in func_a()
    for item in items:
        value += item.value_b
        count += 1

    obj.attribute_b = value
    avg = value / count

    # Do some other stuff just as in func_a()...
```

Please notice how when assigning to the obj, a different attribute is used for each method. This gets me to the point where I don't know if the right thing is to keep both methods and just extract the things that are similar. I've been trying so hard to somehow just make it into method that can do both but can't quite get it.

Comment: seems like a better question for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: is `obj` the same type of object in both scenarios, i.e., `obj` contains both `attribute_a` and `attribute_b` (and likewise `item` contains both `value_a` & `value_b`)?. Seems like maybe these should be a dict e.g., `obj.attributes` and `item.values`. Then you could pass the string key `'a'` or `'b'` as needed.

Comment: @DavidZemens Yes they are, the problem is that this is in reality a Django project and that `obj` is an object that represents a Model from the database, so changing its attributes wouldn't be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine both methods, but you will need to pass a variable(like flag) to identify flow - to go with a or b. Like below

```
def func_ab(data, is_a=True):
    obj = get_obj_from(data)
    value = 0
    count = 0

    for item in items:
        if is_a:
            value += item.value_a
        else:
            value += item.value_b
            count += 1

    if is_a:
        obj.attribute_a = value
    else:
        obj.attribute_b = value
        avg = value / count
```

`is_a` has default value of True so while calling this function for a you can call as `func_ab(data)` and while calling for b `func_ab(data, False)`

Hope this helps!

You can further refactor:

```
def func_ab(data, is_a=True):
    obj = get_obj_from(data)

    if is_a:
        obj.attribute_a = sum([item.value_a for item in items])
    else:
        obj.attribute_b = sum([item.value_b for item in items])
        avg = obj.attribute_b / len(items)
```

Comment: This is indeed the only solution I've been able to come across, I just wanna know if people consider this acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of some of the builtins like `getattr` and `setattr`.

```
def func(data, att_key='a'):
    obj = get_obj_from(data)
    att_name = f'attribute_{att_key}'
    value_name = f'value_{att_key}'
    # sets the obj.{att_name} to the sum of the item.{value_name}
    setattr(obj, att_name, sum([getattr(item, value_name) for item in items]) )
    if att_key == 'b':
        avg = obj.attribute_b / len(items)
```

This is flexible to handle additional cases if you have more than just `'a'` and `'b'` to worry about.